# Printing Barbeque Barcodes

Tags: java, printing, barcode-printing

I've been reading examples for printing in Java for hours, but I haven't found the right site I guess. My problem is, that I want to print 5 barcodes (created with barbeque project) on 1 page in a form like that:

The first 4 barcodes in font size 16
|||||||||||||||||||||
00000001
|||||||||||||||||||||
00000002
|||||||||||||||||||||
00000003
|||||||||||||||||||||
00000004
The last Barcode in font size 24
||||||||||||||||
ZZ0064

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare barcode images via [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and [Font](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) classes.

After that use [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html) to print the result image.